# ViewPagerIndicator tabs loses content

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewpagerindicator, android-holo-everywhere

I am using `Holoeverywhere` and `ViewPagerIndicator`; using `Holoeverywhere1` I implemented the `slider` and tabs in the `Fragment` using `ViewPagerIndicator`. Everything is working fine, Slider working, the menu in it, the tabs; the tabs works fine only the first time, when I move to other `Fragment` using the `slider` and come back to the tabs `Fragment`, the contents are no more available.

Code for the `Fragment` where tabs are created

```
public class SeconFrag extends Fragment {

    ViewPager mViewPager;
    FragmentAdapter mTabsAdapter;
    PageIndicator mIndicator;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mTabsAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_frag);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mTabsAdapter);



        TitlePageIndicator indicator = (TitlePageIndicator) view
                .findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);
        indicator.setFooterIndicatorStyle(IndicatorStyle.Triangle);
        mIndicator = indicator;

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Create");

    }


}
```

`FragmentAdapter` code

```
public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    protected static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "Choose", "Customise" };

    private int mCount = CONTENT.length;

    public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return  TabOne.newInstance();
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return  TabTwo.newInstance();
        }else if (position == 3 ) {
            return  TabOne.newInstance();
        }else 
            return  null;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
      return FragmentAdapter.CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length];
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        if (count > 0 && count <= 10) {
            mCount = count;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

on of the tab `Fragment`

```
public final class TabOne extends Fragment {

    public static TabOne newInstance() {
        TabOne fragment = new TabOne();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_one, container,
                false);
        return myFragmentView;
    }
}
```

in the `SeconFrag` `OnPause()` I removed the `Fragment` no luck, `hide()` it in the `OnPause()` and tried to `show()` in the `OnResume()` still not showing content after the `Fragment` is changed.

**EDIT**

[image: First time opening the fragment]
[image: Change Fragment using slider]
[image: Contents gone]